# Tkinter function creates variable that can't be added to list with .get() from entry

Tags: python, list, tkinter, button, get

First off, I am aware that there are many questions out there with .get() not properly working and I have read through many of them.
My issue is that my program has a button that every time it is pressed, it adds a new entry box for a new Player to be added, then I then want to create a Player object (I have the player class defined in another file) and add the Player object to a list.
Here is the function for the "Add Player" button:

```
def add_player():
    new_player = Label(team_wind, text='Enter an NBA Player:')
    new_player_entry = Entry(team_wind, width=30)
    new_player.pack()
    new_player_entry.pack()
    team_wind.mainloop()
    player_list.append(new_player_entry.get())
```

(team_wind is the window because it is creating a Team of Players. the Team class is also defined in another file)
After some reaserch, I realized that mainloop would terminate that block of code (as far as my understanding). So, when I run the program, the entry returns ''. I know this is a very common issue, but it is wierd for mine because I can't figure out a way to get around it. I already have a working part of the tkinter window for a single player with a single entry box, so I know how .get() works. I've tried using .update() and .update_idletasks().

- I have tried moving the player_list.append to before the mainloop
  because I know the code after is unreachable, but if I move it to
  before, then it returns nothing

. If I try to do it in another function or after the code terminates, then it won't work because if the button is pressed multiple times, each entry will have the same variable name. I think this means it has to be done in this function, but not sure how to do that with mainloop. Here is the code to create the window so it will run. All I need is for it to be able to print or return the list with the player objects for however many players there are (depends how many times the button is pressed).
I have provided the code needed to run the program and cut out everything else that would cause errors. Thanks

```
     from tkinter import *
    player_list = []    
    def add_player():
        new_player = Label(team_wind, text='Enter an NBA Player:')
        new_player_entry = Entry(team_wind, width=30)
        new_player.pack()
        new_player_entry.pack()
        team_wind.mainloop()
        player_list.append(new_player_entry.get())
    
    def main():
        #setup
        global team_name
        global team_wind
        global player_entry
        global player_entry2
        team_wind = Tk()
        team_wind.title('Team')
        team_wind.geometry('800x500')
    
        #Text entries
        team_mode_title = Label(team_wind, text='Make a team of NBA Players and find their stats')
        player = Label(team_wind, text='Enter an NBA Player:')
        player2 = Label(team_wind, text='Enter an NBA Player:')
        
        #Text Box Entries
        player_entry = Entry(team_wind, width=30)
        player_entry2 = Entry(team_wind, width=30)
    
        #BUTTONS
        add_player_button = Button(team_wind, text='Add player', command=add_player)
    

        #Button for StackOverflow question to print the list of players
            print_list_button = Button(team_wind, text='Print List', command=print_list)
            #Pack
            team_mode_title.pack()
            #avg_button.pack()
            add_player_button.pack()
            print_list_button.pack()
            player.pack()
            player_entry.pack()
       

 player2.pack()
        player_entry2.pack()
    
        team_wind.mainloop()
    

def print_list():
    player_list.append(player_entry.get())
    player_list.append(player_entry2.get())
    print(player_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One problem is that you call `mainloop` more than once. You should only ever call it once for the life of the program.  Calling `mainloop` in your function is going to cause other problems that will be hard to diagnose. Why do you think it's important to call it here? What do you expect it to do? Are you expecting it to pause the code until the user enters some data?

Comment: you should have `mainloop()` only in `main()` and for adding items to list you should use some button which get value from Entry and append to list - so it will do it when you already will have value in `Entry. OR you could `bind` key `Enter` (or rather `Return`) to run this function when you press `Enter`.

Comment: as for `entry returns ''` - it is not issues, it is how most GUI frameworks work (not only tkinter but also PyQt, wxPython, and GUIs in other languages) - `Entry` doesn't work like `input()` and it doesn't wait for your text and Enter - it only inform window that you want to display Entry. Rest should be resolver with functions assigned to Buttons or with `events` assigned to widgets

Comment: if you need many new_player then you should keep all `Entry` on list (without using `.get()`) and later use `.get()` (in for-loop) to get values from all `Entries`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only one `mainloop()` - in `main()`.

You could use your list to keep widgets `Entry` - without using `.get()` - and you should use `.get()` when you print list.

---

Minimal working code.

I used `Frame` to keep `Label` and `Entry` and this way it adds `Entry` before `Buttons`.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

def add_player():
    label = tk.Label(frame, text='Enter an NBA Player:')
    label.pack()
    
    entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=30)
    entry.pack()
    
    entry_list.append( entry )  # add full widget, not value from widget

def print_list():
    for number, entry in enumerate(entry_list, 1):
        print( number, entry.get() )

def main():
    global team_wind
    global frame

    team_wind = tk.Tk()
    team_wind.title('Team')
    team_wind.geometry('800x500')

    team_mode_title = tk.Label(team_wind, text='Make a team of NBA Players and find their stats')
    team_mode_title.pack()

    # frame to keep all Entries
    frame = tk.Frame(team_wind)
    frame.pack()
    
    # at start add Entries for two players
    add_player()    
    add_player()
    
    # button to add Entry for next player
    add_player_button = tk.Button(team_wind, text='Add player', command=add_player)
    add_player_button.pack()

    # button to print values from all Entries
    print_list_button = tk.Button(team_wind, text='Print List', command=print_list)
    print_list_button.pack()

    team_wind.mainloop()

# --- main ---

entry_list = []

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up changin the format of it based of the idea of someone else to use a submit button and just reset the entry box.                                                                          
def submit_player():
    player_list.append(Player(player_entry.get()))
    player_entry.delete(0, 'end')

Comment: The only reason I am doing it that way is then I can add however many players i want to the team. Right now, I think If I added too many players then the entry boxes would go off the screen. This solution does, however, have an advantage where I can edit the player boxes instead of having to reset them all to change 1 player. I learned a lot from this solution too. Thanks

Comment: you can check `len(entry_list)` to stop adding too much entries. OR maybe you should use widget Text to get all players at once as multilines-text.

Answer (score 1):

Once your program reaches the `team_wind.mainloop()` command nothing under it will execute because python will continute running mainloop() forever. This means that the function will never get to running `player_list.append(Player(new_player_entry.get()))`.

Comment: Yes, I address that concern in my problem analysis (sorry if its long). But if I move it to before the mainloop, then it returns '' because it hasn't run the mainloop yet.

Comment: I would recommend creating a submit button that when clicked appended the result instead of doing it imedeatly or on a delay. It would probably be easier that way.

Comment: I have thought of using a submit button, but thats basically what the button I already have does. For this problem, i changed it to "print list" for simplicity. I think the way you're describing would involve having a submit button for each entry, which I don't want. I might try right now having only one entry box and hitting submit each time with a reset option. That might be better overall anyway. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You don't need to have a submit button for each entry. I would have one submit button that appends the data from all the entrys.

Comment: That would run into the same problem that the print button already has, which is it doesn't know how many entries there are.

Comment: I made the submit button and it works. Thank you!